# mathcal inside gather environment not working

Tags: math-mode, align

I'm trying to display a sequence of equations, plainly centred, so without any alignment you get from the align environment. I thought `gather` would do the job, but when I try to use `mathcal`, I get the error:

`! LaTeX Error: \mathcal allowed only in math mode.`

It works fine using align. What am I doing wrong?

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
p(f) &= \mathcal{N}\left(f; 0, K\right)
\end{align*}

\begin{gather}
p(f) &= \mathcal{N}\left(f; 0, K\right)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove that `& `in `&=` from within `gather`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You shouldn't use `&` in `gather`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For several reasons some error catching in AMS environments is awkward; this is a case. The error is not really in `\mathcal`; indeed, if you remove it, the first error message is

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

If you also remove `\left` and `\right` (that shouldn't be there to begin with), the error becomes

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

Hmm, there's something wrong with `&`. And this is the real problem: the `gather` environment has no alignment point, so `&` must not be used in it.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
p(f) &= \mathcal{N}(f; 0, K) \\
q(f) &= \mathcal{N}(f; K, 0) + 3
\end{align*}

\begin{gather}
p(f) = \mathcal{N}(f; 0, K) \\
q(f) = \mathcal{N}(f; K, 0) + 3
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I removed `\left` and `\right` that here only do damages. I also removed the call to the `a4` package that's obsolete and deprecated.

Don't use `align` or `gather` as substitutes for `equation` (or `equation*`) when you have just one formula: they're for multiline displays.

Comment: Because of a bad interaction between `hyperref` and the `equation` environment, the `hyperref` documentation actually recommends using `gather` instead of `equation`.

Comment: @Dan I can't agree.

Comment: Then you may have spacing problems for `equation` if you use hyperref. These seem to be rare (I've never had the problem), but the hyperref `README` file does suggest substituting `gather` when it occurs.